# SQL syntax error in MySQL unsing a cast(Partition as Signed)

Tags: mysql

I have to support an application on a `MySQL server.` I can´t change the source code so I can´t change the used syntax.
My problem is that I always get an syntax error like this:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers [-2147217900]
>        [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.6.26]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'Partition as Signed)' at
>   line 1

I looked into the log file and found the problem in this line:

```
Select * 
from XYZ 
where `Type`='something' 
and Client='{3DBEA33A-9F0A-4e86-8354-F652713EA458}' 
order by Cast(Partition as Signed);
```

I always get this error when the `"Cast(Partition as Signed)"` appears.

Is there any way to configure the server to accept this syntax?

I´m using `MySQL (x64) 5.6.26 with InnoDB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Partition` is reserved word.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html

you should use it with backticks

```
`Partition`
```